# Check equality with Python dataframe containing None values

Tags: python, dataframe, nonetype

I'm comparing a dataframe to a dict as follows...

```
if not ( (df['Column1'] == a['Column1']) & (df['Column2'] == a['Column2']) ).any():
    print("not in list")
```

Both my dataframe (df) and dict (a) may contain a None value, but I've noticed that when 2 None values are compared, they are not deemed to be equal and so I'm printing "not in list" even though both df and a both hold the same value.

Any thoughts on the best way around this issue would be really appreciated.  Perhaps I have to convert the None values to a string that will return True when compared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `np.NAN == np.NAN`resolves to False. You can use `pd.DataFrame.equals`, which considers NaNs in the same locations as being equal. In code that reads like

```py
if df[['Column1', 'Column2']].equals(a[['Column1', 'Column2']]):
```

Comment: Thanks, should this work with None as well as NaN?  I have specifically forced None into the dataframe using df = df.where(df.notnull(), None).

Comment: Also workes with Nones

Comment: Great thanks, I've accepted the answer, but any ideas how to check equality if the other value (Column2) was a simple None variable (instead of dataframe or series)?  I notice Dataframe.equals requires a series/dataframe as a parameter

Comment: Oof, good question. In that case, you may need to ensure the validity of the dataframe/series before you actually do the comparison. Maybe do a prior check of the column or matrix dimension.